# PayPal REST API billing plans & agreements (subscriptions)

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I want to use the PayPal REST API to offer subscriptions on my website. According to the documentation a billing plan is required in order to create a billing agreement with a user.

While the documentation explains how to create billing plans/agreements, I still have a few questions which the documentation does not answer:

- Is a billing plan used for multiple billing agreements? For example, you create a billing plan for each service on your website and let users subscribe to this.
- Does each billing agreement need a new billing plan? (in contrast to the previous question)
- If I delete a billing plan, does this also remove all dependent billing agreements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: This may not be a '"direct" programming question, but these concepts are only used within the PayPal REST API, which to me, seems to be related to programming

Comment: Your question is about billing plans and agreements, not about programming them.

Comment: Sure, but where do you suggest I ask this question?

Comment: I meant to look. I don't know if there is a PayPal stackexchange but you can look at the bottom of this page. Otherwise, there must be a PayPal forum somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late answer but I am facing the same problem right now and found [this link](https://devblog.paypal.com/subscriptions-are-now-available-in-the-paypal-rest-apis/). The article is from 2014 but still can be useful because explains a little bit of what you are asking about. Reading it **I think that billing plan can be used for multiple agreements**. You just need to create the plan and then use the ID for agreements.

Anyway, I suggest you to use [sandbox mode](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/) to test all features.

Also, if you found another answer which explains the mechanism better, please post it here.

Hope I could help.